# Angular get length of filtered ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have upgraded to Angular 1.2.9 from v 1.0.8 to help with the performance of my app.

I have introduced track by which has improved the speed.

What I used to have

```
<div class="result row"
    data-ng-repeat="result in (filteredItems =
            (results |
            filter: filterPrice |
            filter: filterCategories |
            filter: filterTypes |
            filter: filterAirConditioning |
            filter: filterTransmission |
            filter: filterFourByFour |
            filter: filterFuelType |
            filter: filterNumberOfDoors |
            filter: filterOnAirport |
            filter: filterFuelPolicy |
            filter: filterUnlimitedMileage |
            filter: filterFreeCancellation |
            filter: filterTheftProtection |
            filter: filterCDW |
            filter: filterTaxesIncluded |
            filter: filterProviders ) )  |
        orderBy: [orderByOptions, orderByPriceLowToHigh, orderByPriority] |
        limitTo: pageSize">
```

what I have now

```
<div class="result row"
    data-ng-repeat="result in results |
        filter: filterPrice |
        filter: filterCarCategories |
        filter: filterCarTypes |
        filter: filterAirConditioning |
        filter: filterTransmission |
        filter: filterFourByFour |
        filter: filterFuelType |
        filter: filterNumberOfDoors |
        filter: filterOnAirport |
        filter: filterFuelPolicy |
        filter: filterUnlimitedMileage |
        filter: filterFreeCancellation |
        filter: filterTheftProtection |
        filter: filterCDW |
        filter: filterTaxesIncluded |
        filter: filterProviders |
        orderBy: [orderByOptions, orderByPriceLowToHigh, orderByPriority] |
        startFrom: currentPage*pageSize |
        limitTo: pageSize track by $index">
```

I have pagination which looked for the length of filteredItems. That no longer exists. Also, some other JS needs the filteredItems for logging, analytics, etc

In the HTML view I can get the length of the ng-repeat after filters have been applied

```
{{(results |
    filter: filterPrice |
    filter: filterCarCategories |
    filter: filterCarTypes |
    filter: filterAirConditioning |
    filter: filterTransmission |
    filter: filterFourByFour |
    filter: filterFuelType |
    filter: filterNumberOfDoors |
    filter: filterOnAirport |
    filter: filterFuelPolicy |
    filter: filterUnlimitedMileage |
    filter: filterFreeCancellation |
    filter: filterTheftProtection |
    filter: filterCDW |
    filter: filterTaxesIncluded |
    filter: filterProviders)
    .length}}
```

which is a bit of a mouthful but does return the number I want. How can I pass this to a $scope ?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can create an intermediate variable that will hold the filtered array:

```
data-ng-repeat="result in filteredResults = (results | filter:filterPrice | filter:filterCarCategories | etc.)"
```

and then can use:

```
filteredResults.length
```

Comment: Hi Gruff Bunny, I did have something similar to that, see first bit of the code. I've just tried your version but get this error: Error: [ngRepeat:dupes]

Comment: I assumed I had to setup a $scope.filteredResults, so did so.

Comment: Have you got track by $index at the end of the expression (to cope with duplicates)?

Comment: got it here:      <div class="result row" data-ng-repeat="result in (filteredResults = results | filter:filterPrice ... filter: filterProviders) | orderBy: [orderByOptions, orderByPriceLowToHigh, orderByPriority] | limitTo:pageSize track by $index">

It's now not throwing an error but filteredResults.length returns the total results array, and doesn't change after a filter is applied.

I'll knock up a demo...

Comment: Actually, it returns the correct amount if I moved the bracket to a different place <div class="result row" data-ng-repeat="result in filteredResults = (results | filter:filterPrice | fi...

Comment: Sorry, I've made a mistake here. You're version works, so I'll mark it as the right answer. I get the dupes issue with something to do with my pagination.