# Determining how many results are shown by ng-repeat filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

If I use `ng-repeat` with `filter`, how can I determine how many elements are filtered out (or vice versa, how many are shown)? Specifically, I would like to create a search bar that creates the filter, but I would also like to show how many elements are hidden by the filter (ie something like `Showing 6 of 10 results`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see here http://jsbin.com/xuyuy/1/edit

In your repeater you can create new array ie : personsfiltered

```
ng-repeat="person in personsfilterd = (persons | filter : search )
```

and after that just display length of orignal array and filtered array :

```
Showing {{personsfilterd.length}} of {{persons.length }} results
```

Full code here:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('fCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.persons = [
    'Mike', 'Tom', 'Tim', 'Jim', 'Ken'
  ]

});

 <div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="fCtrl">
      <input type="text" ng-model = "search"> Showing {{personsfilterd.length}} of {{persons.length }} results
      <li ng-repeat="person in personsfilterd = (persons | filter : search )">{{person}}</li>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I was using this for a while and it was working great, but it stopped working for some reason. Can you perhaps opine on my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26341910/variable-set-in-ng-repeat-not-being-created

Answer (score 0):

First, the `ngRepeat` has these: `$index`, `$first`, `$middle`, `$last` for determining the current position. So I guess you may be interested in the `$last`. What I'm not sure about is whether it will pick up the original count or the filtered one.

EDIT:
You can obtain the count of original value from your ctrl, by setting the `varX.length` and using that in your template (HTML code) and then, assuming that `$last` is returning the final count+1 (as it's 0-based) you can have the count after filter is applied.

[ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21379765/1305516). The solution is to assign the filtered data to a new variable in the `ng-repeat`. Potentially could cause some memory issues, but not really relevant in my case.