# Variable set in ng-repeat not being created

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26218823/determining-how-many-results-are-shown-by-ng-repeat-filter) question on how to determine number of filtered out elements, I created the following angular code:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="query" placeholder="Enter query...">
<div ng-if="filteredData.length!=data.length"> Showing {{filteredData.length}} of {{data.length}}</div>
<div ng-repeat="datum in filteredData = (data | orderBy: 'name' : reverse | filter:query)"> 
    ....
</div>
```

However, for some reason `filteredData` never actually gets set and `Showing  of 10` always appears. I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13744085/1305516) answer to get the scope variable for my controller, but `filteredData` doesn't show up there despite all the other variables showing up.

Also worth noting: the contents of the repeat work fine, its just that `filteredData` that isnt being set.

Comment: please see here http://jsbin.com/xuyuy/3/edit I've used your code and everything seems fine. have you any error on console ?

Comment: @sss I figured out the issue. Its because my `ng-repeat` was wrapped in an `ng-if`, while the rest of the code wasn't. However, the `ng-if` was always evaluating to true, so I don't know why the `ng-if` was causing issues.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because you are trying to set filteredData within your ng-repeat.

You should probably be setting filteredData to be a filtered set of your data in the controller. That way you are just looping in your repeat statement.

```
<div ng-repeat="datum in filteredData | orderBy: 'name' : reverse | filter:query"> 
    ....
</div>
```

It's also probably worth noting that angular filter in ng-repeat wont edit your array's length. So in the case that your code actually DID work the filteredData.length wouldn't change.

Comment: The angular filter is not meant to change the arrays length, its meant to create a subset and assign it to a new array,`filteredData`, which will have a smaller length. This used to work, but now it stopped working for some reason. Doing it inside out outside of the controller shouldn't matter.